# Symfony 1.4 Doctrine_query how to set parameter?

Tags: doctrine, symfony1

I would like to bind a parameter to my doctrine request using the `setParams` function . Following is my code, please correct me if you see any mistakes.

```
$input = $request->getParameter('query');

 $result = Doctrine_Query::create()
            ->from('jobeetCategory')
            ->where("name LIKE '$:name'")
            ->setParams(['name'=>$input])
            ->fetchArray();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to try to use `setParams()`:

```
$result = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('jobeetCategory')
        ->where('name LIKE ?', $input)
        ->fetchArray()
;
```

From the Sf1.4 docs:

> ```
>   ->where('j.expires_at > ?', date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()));`
> ```

BTW i see by the 'jobeet' that you are following the symfony 1.4 beginner tutorial.If you are beginner to symfony 1.4 and are not forced to use it you should definitely learn Symfony 2/3 instead, symfony 1.4 is no longer supported by sensiolabs and the community is pretty dead.(and Symfony 2/3 is awesome)

**EDIT:**

If you have more conditions just use `andWhere()` or 'orWhere()' as much as you need

```
$result = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('jobeetCategory')
    ->where('name LIKE ?', $input['name'])
    ->andWhere('price < ?', $input['price'])
    ->orWhere('shipping > ?', $input['shipping'])
    ->fetchArray()
;
```

For further reference: http://doctrine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#where-clause

Comment: Thank for your answering and advise. I study s1.4 is coz of my current working company still using and maintaining. By the way, I have one more question is the where() parameter 2 can set as array? I would like to have more than one condition.